# Can I return a template and a variable separately from a single Django function?

Tags: django

I am writing an ajax call.  The call returns HTML.  However, I only want to actually load the new HTML if a certain thing happened on the backend (either an insert or a delete action occurred).

Thus, I want to return two variables from Django.  (1) The html, that I will only load if the second variable (2) returns true or false.

Although this won't be very useful, a sample function is below:

```
def update_party_and_company_data(request):
  parties, companies, reload = get_the_data()
  context = {'parties': [list of parties],
            'companies': [list of companies],}


  html = render(request, 'setup_parties_data.html', context)
  reload_instruction = reload

  return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'html': html , 'reload_instruction ': reload_instruction }))
```

Comment: That's a legitimate approach (althogh do you need to render and send the HTML if you're not going to use it). What's your question? You can send one json response that has whatever data you want in it, if that answers the Q.

Comment: One of the variables needs to be a rendered template.  If the second variable is True, I will load the html.

Comment: That's not a question :D

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by rendering the template using render_to_string:

def update_party_and_company_data(request):

```
  parties, companies, reload = get_data()
  context = {'parties': parties,
        'companies': companies,
        }


  html = render_to_string('setup_parties_data.html', context)
  return JsonResponse({'html': html, 'reload': reload})
```